Issue with Global Theme in StyledComponents (React Native)
Issue with Global Theme in StyledComponents (React Native)
In my component, when I try to use a color from my global theme and set:
background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.}

the options inside theme, such as colors, font-size, etc., do not appear when I type the "dot". What is wrong?
My styles.ts file inside src/screens/Groups/:
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray_700};
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
`;

My index.ts file inside src/theme/:
export default {
  colors: {
    white: '#FFFFFF',
    green_700: '#00875F',
    green_500: '#00B37E',
    red: '#F75A68',
    red_dark: '#AA2834',
    gray_700: '#121214',
    gray_600: '#202024',
    gray_500: '#29292E',
    gray_400: '#323238',
    gray_300: '#7C7C8A',
    gray_200: '#C4C4CC',
    gray_100: '#E1E1E6'
  },
  fontFamily: {
    regular: 'Roboto_400Regular',
    bold: 'Roboto_700Bold'
  },
  fontSize: {
    sm: 14,
    md: 16,
    lg: 18,
    xl: 24
  }
};

My styled.d.ts file inside src/@types/:
import 'styled-components';
import theme from '../theme';

declare module 'styled-components' {
  type ThemeType = typeof theme;

  export interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeType { }
}

My index.tsx file inside app/:
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";
import theme from "../src/theme";
import { Groups } from '@screens/Groups';

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Groups />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

I tried to resolve this issue with several YouTube tutorials but couldn't. Could it be that I'm missing an extension in VSCode?

Feel free to adjust or add any additional details before posting.

i resolve this problem:
import styled, { css } from "styled-components/native";
export const Container = styled.View   ${({}) => css
flex: 1;
background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.COLORS.GRAY_700};
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
} ;

This is because you need to create the TypeScript property to show the suggestions.
If you don't use TS, please import the theme directly in your module to show the suggestions.


